# should I use a determiner before this nominalised adjective?

Tags: determiners

Is it preferable to say referring to Gulliver "You're a giant in the land of small" or "you're a giant in the land of the small" or "you're a giant in the land of (the) small people"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"In the land of small" is possibly ungrammatical, and certainly unidiomatic.

"in the land of the small" is somewhat literary, but perfectly accceptable.

"In the land of (the) small people" is fine with or without the article.

For reasons I cannot explain, "little" fits much better for me than "small" here.